# jinja2 - read items vars from yml in order

Tags: jinja2, python-2.x

The following code works but the output is randomize. I would like to know how to let the python script to read in order (top-down) and output.

template.j2

```
{% for iface in ifaces %}
bridge-domain NAME-{{ ifaces[iface]['bviif'] }}
   mac
    aging
     time 30000
    !
    limit
     maximum 128000
     notification both
    !
    port-down flush disable
   !
   igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
   interface Bundle-Ether501.{{ ifaces[iface][bviif] }}
    dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UpLink
    static-mac-address 0001
    static-mac-address 0002
   !
   interface {{ iface }}
    dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UN
    split-horizon group
   !
   routed interface {{ ifaces[iface]['bviif'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

datavars.yml

```
    ifaces:
            GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.232:
             bviif: 232
            GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.233:
             bviif: 233
            GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.234:
             bviif: 234
            GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.253:
             bviif: 253
            GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.254:
             bviif: 254
            GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.255:
             bviif: 255
            GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.256:
             bviif: 256
            GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.257:
             bviif: 257
[...] until 100/0/0/14.xxx
```

prerender.py

```
from jinja2 import Template
import yaml
import sys
from glob import glob

datavars_fname = sys.argv[1:1] or glob('*.yml')[0]
template_fname = sys.argv[2:2] or glob('*.j2')[0]

datavars = yaml.load(open(datavars_fname).read())
template = Template(open(template_fname).read())

print template.render(datavars)
```

with that code, I have the following results:

```
bridge-domain NAME-255
   mac
    aging
    time 30000
   !
    limit
     maximum 128000
     notification both
    !
    port-down flush disable
   !
   igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
   interface Bundle-Ether501.255
    dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UpLink
    static-mac-address 0001
    static-mac-address 0002
   !
   interface GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.255
    dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UN
    split-horizon group
   !
   routed interface BVI255

bridge-domain Name-254
   mac
    aging
     time 30000
    !
   limit
     maximum 128000
     notification both
    !
    port-down flush disable
   !
   igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
   interface Bundle-Ether701.254
    dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UpLink
    static-mac-address 0001
    static-mac-address 0002
   !
   interface GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.254
    dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UN
    split-horizon group
   !
   routed interface BVI254
```

[...]
as you can see, it starts randomly from .255 even if in the datavars.yml it starts from .232

Expected results:

```
bridge-domain NAME-232
    mac
     aging
      time 30000
     !
     limit
      maximum 128000
      notification both
         !
     port-down flush disable
    !
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
interface Bundle-Ether501.232
 dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UpLink
 static-mac-address 0001
 static-mac-address 0002
!
interface GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.232
 dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UN
 split-horizon group
!
routed interface BVI232

bridge-domain Name-233
mac
 aging
  time 30000
 !
 limit
  maximum 128000
  notification both
 !
 port-down flush disable
!
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
interface Bundle-Ether701.233
 dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UpLink
 static-mac-address 0001
 static-mac-address 0002
!
interface GigabitEthernet100/0/0/10.233
 dhcp ipv4 snoop profile UN
 split-horizon group
!
routed interface BVI233
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it installing oyaml and import it.

import oyaml as yaml

Thank you!